# hangfire is not running when i deploy my asp.net mvc-5 web application on iis 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, hangfire

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. and i install the hangfire tool inside my web application using nuget tool.

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire/
```

Then i create the following `startup.cs` class, to call a method each minute as follow:-

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .UseSqlServerStorage("scanservice");


            ScanningService ss = new ScanningService();
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => ss.HypervisorScan("allscan"), Cron.Minutely);

        }

    }
```

and here is the definition of the method that will be called :-

```
public async Task<ScanResult> HypervisorScan(string FQDN)
{
```

but currently i deploy my application on IIS 7.5 , and the method is not being called at all . so can anyone adivce on this please ?

Thanks

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your `Startup` class, does it get reached? If you add the Hangfire dashboard (`app.UseHangfireDashboard();`) and then access the `~/hangfire` URL, do you see the job there? Do you have the OwinStartupAttribute (`[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyWebApplication.Startup))]`) in your Startup class?

Comment: @mason why i need to add the OwinStartupAttribute ? i did not get any error ,,, or this is mandetory to add even if VS did not raise any error ?

Comment: after adding the referecne i am getting the following exception "Async methods are not supported. Please make them synchronous before using them in background." ,, could this be related that the metohd i am calling is async ?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the OwinStartupAttribute from your class. Add it. That tells OWIN where the code is to run at startup.

Also, [you can't run async methods directly in Hangfire](http://discuss.hangfire.io/t/async-task-jobs/73) as the error clearly states. So wrap the method with a Wait call and pass that to Hangfire.

Lastly, you should stick with the convention that Async methods should end in the suffix Async. Rename `ScanningService.HypervisorScan` to `ScanningService.HypervisorScanAsync`

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyWebApplication.Startup))]
namespace MyWebApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .UseSqlServerStorage("scanservice");    


            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => HypervisorScan(), Cron.Minutely);
        }

       public void HypervisorScan()
       {
           ScanningService ss = new ScanningService();
           ss.HypervisorScanAsync("allscan").Wait();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: but at the end using .Wait() will occupy the thread as it is a blocking operation.so it is not recommended to use .Wait() as it is a blocking method , unlike using await which is 100% async .. so seems if i use hangfire i will have to break the async behavioure for my methods.thanks

Comment: @johnG Hangfire doesn't *need* async methods, because by its very definition it runs things asynchronously. When you `AddOrUpdate` a job, it takes the method call from the lambda and adds it to it's list of scheduled jobs. So that's asynchronous, just no need to make use of the C# async concept.

Comment: but the problem is with this "ss.HypervisorScanAsync("allscan").Wait();" as using wait() in this way means that the iis thread will be occupied till the end of the operation,,